# How to create a view for calendar in React, how will render the elements of an array as follows?

Tags: html, reactjs

28 29 30 31 1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8

I need this for a calendar component I'm making I need to get to the bottom line every 7 days.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this in React Native, idea is the same.

```
const days = [ 28,29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

return (
   <View
      style={{ flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap", marginVertical: 10 }}
    >
      {days.map((day) => (
        <View
          key={day}
          style={{
            width: `${100 / 7}%`,
            height: 20,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        >
          <Text >{day}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
)
```

[image]

Comment: When you need 1-30 as an Array: `Array.from({length: 30}, (o,i)=>i+1)`.
Similarly the other 2 ranges can be generated & then concatenated.

Comment: It worked for me thanks. For the React code I edited it as follows.
 `const renderCalender = params => {
    return (
      <div
      style={{display: "flex",width: 280, flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap", marginVertical: 10 }}>
      {monthArray?.map((el,index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            width: 40,
            height: 20,
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        >
          <span >{el.date}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    );
  };`

Answer (score 0):

Hi there why are you creating a view for calendar? Why not install a package like `DateTimePickerModal`? Already got all the Date functionality/Calendar included

Check out here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker